# Is there a dual basis analogue for trialities?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

Let $\mathbb F$ be a field, $A, B, C$ vector spaces over this field and $f : A \times B \times C \to \mathbb F$ a triality. That is, $f$ is linear in its parameters and for any nonzero $b, c$ there is an $a$ such that $f(a, b, c) \neq 0$ and similar conditions hold for $b$ and $c$.
Let $a_i$, $b_i$, $c_i$ be finite bases of corresponding spaces.

**Question**. Is there a notion analogous to that of "dual basis" - a relation on $a_i$, $b_i$, $c_i$, a sense in which it's a "good" or "correct" triplet of bases in the given spaces? Maybe there is some notion that only works when some restrictions are put on $\mathbb F$?

Comment: The usual dual basis takes advantage of the fact that any $f:A \times B \to \Bbb F$ can be written in the form
$$
f(a,b) = \sum_{k=1}^d f_k(a)g_j(b)
$$
for some $f_k:A \to \Bbb F$, $g_k : B \to \Bbb F$, and $d$ equal to the maximum of the dimensions of $A,B$. Unfortunately, the "obvious" analogous statement fails to hold for trialities.

Comment: @BenGrossmann there is more or less obvious statement $$f(a,b,c) = \sum_{k=1}^{d^3} f_k(a)g_k(b)h_k(c)$$. If the $d^3$ in the sum could be reduced to a smaller number, i feel like it would give some progress on the main question. Maybe $d^2*3$? It's hard to visualize 3d bricks of numbers and how they can be reduced